# PHP - Are there any real benefits to calling die() instead of echo?

Tags: php, performance, optimization, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm attempting to figure out if there are any benefits for memory usage if I call `die(json_encode($array));` instead of just echoing the results and letting the script end. I imagine that it partly depends on the script, but I'm asking in the scenario where it works fine logically, but other conditionals will be checked further down the script but not executed, meaning variables are still in memory and code still runs in the script.

Are there any memory/CPU saving effects from calling `die()` or `exit()` to `echo` my JSON data from an AJAX request? Will memory from variables and the script's execution be freed sooner if I replace `echo` in my scripts?

Comment: if your script immediately terminates after the `echo` then there should be no need to call `die`. i doubt there are any savings to be had. if there's a bunch of `if`s below that won't be executed, then sure...you can save a few CPU cycles. probably nothing significant though

Comment: Do you know if it is considered best practice to either a) make multiple files for larger logical requirements, or b) call `die()` to save CPU cycles? I assume (a). I'm planning for the potential need of every CPU cycle towards the beginning of this application's life cycle, so if it will save a few CPU cycles, it might be worth it even with smaller scripts..

Comment: if you need to free up memory a few milliseconds earlier, you're probably running too close to max anyway and should resolve the problem by ensuring some headroom there.

Comment: If I wanted to be responsible instead of frugal. Duely noted though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: This would be best suited to being benchmarked in your environment. Where one environment may favor one method, another may not. However there are internal implications to the usage of `die` /`exit`in comparison to other methods, such as return codes or handling of  destructors. To be clear though [`die` is equivalent to `exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)

Comment: Yeah, I know that die is just an alias for exit often used syntatically for error handling. I was just curious if anyone in the community had experience with the implications of replacing echo with terminating the process for AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`die()` is equivalent to `exit()`. There is no meaningful difference and any difference would likely be implementation based. Most prefer to use `exit()` for a routine exit and `die()` in situations where there is an error. This could be due to readability and nothing more.